# Can I force dnf to install an old version of a package?

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf

I want to install an older version of `package <x>`, and when I use `dnf` it only shows the current version of the `package <x>`.

Is there any way to install an older versions using `dnf` ?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can install using a specific name-version as described in the man page:

```
dnf install tito-0.5.6-1.fc22
```

> Install package with specific version. If the package is already
>   installed it will automatically try to downgrade or upgrade to
>   specific version.

To view all versions of a package in your enabled repositories, use:

```
dnf --showduplicates list <package>
```

Comment: Does not work, dnf cannot find the version of the package I just upgraded from.

Comment: The fact that the previous version was just upgraded has nothing to do with it’s availability in the repos. Did you try the showduplicates command? Was it available before the upgrade? I understand it was already installed, that doesn’t necessitate it was present in the repos.

Comment: I believe what Dani is saying is that the `list` command you give in your answer does not show any previous versions of a package. AFAICT it only shows the current version. Have you tried it?

Comment: @AlvinThompson It's not just previous versions. If a particular version is not in the repo, then it won't show, even if it was previously installed. This is an issue with packages installed directly (not from a repo) as well as particular versions having been pulled off from repos due to various reasons (mostly security related).

Answer (score 30):

Yes. You can install older version of package using `dnf downgrade package-name[-version]` if you already installed new one. But the old version still needs to be available on mirrors.

If the package is not available from mirrors, you can always download it manually from [koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/) and then use `dnf` to downgrade such as `dnf downgrade path/to/downloaded.file.rpm`. But with this technique, you might need to resolve dependencies on your own.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that installing packages manually has the disadvantage of not getting any updates (say security fixes) for that package, provided there are any.

Comment: This is not installing packages manually, but just manually downloading them. Anytime you run `dnf update` you will get the updates including security fixes.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I am genuinely curious as I always thought installing an .rpm directly leaves me responsible for installing updated versions of it. Unless the .rpm itself installs its own repository. Can you give a reference for your statement?

Comment: It works that way if you install either a package that is not packaged in your system (from somewhere else) or if you install some newer version than is provided by your system. This particular use case installs an older RPM, from koji (official build system), which means it is most probably included in Fedora and older version so any future update updates it.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I got what you mean, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You can also install older version of a package from koji with `dnf install path/to/downloaded.file.rpm`.

Answer (score 10):

You can perform a simple downgrade by:

```
sudo dnf downgrade <package-name>
```

For instance:

```
sudo dnf downgrade podman
```