# How to install specific version of package in DNF

Tags: fedora, version, dnf

How to install specific package version in DNF. One of my installed package installed the new version, but this new has some issue, then I want to rollback to the old version, but the last old version of the package is still on fc25.

I tried to add the specific version when tried to reinstall but without success. I add this at the end of the package name `2-1.fc25.noarch` and some other combination.

BTW I am on fc26 and the package can be found on the <sub>copr</sub>.

Thanks

Comment: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=306988 please see this link. i guess this will solve your problem

Comment: @RishabhBahukhandi 's answer converted to a comment: *"https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=306988"*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I force dnf to install an old version of a package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266888/can-i-force-dnf-to-install-an-old-version-of-a-package)

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo dnf downgrade --releasever=25 <package-name>`.

But it might be that the old package is no longer available on the COPR repository, it depends on the maintainer.

Answer (score -1):

just list the specific version using the naming convention in the expected order; it's a bit counter intuitive. I.e.; to install a specific version of vim you would use:

```
sudo dnf install vim-common-2:8.0.1763-19.el8.4.x86_64
```

But when you list a specific version using `dnf list` it will display the name in a different manner:

```
sudo dnf list installed | grep vim
vim-common.x86_64                    2:8.0.1763-19.el8.4
```